# Importar valores desde un Diccionario a mis variables Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

```
Inventory_data = {"Inventario_datos": {"Alti MW $ 2 |": {"Floor_price": '2.5', "Li_platform": 1,
                                                    "Excel_name": "Alti MW $ 2.xlsx", "Li_Publisher": 2,
                                                    "Tag_Rate": "2", "TagName": "Alti MW $ 2 |"}},
                                      "Alti MW $ 3 |": {"Floor_price": '2.75', "Li_platform": 1,
                                                    "Excel_name": "Alti MW $ 2.25.xlsx", "Li_Publisher": 2,
                                                    "Tag_Rate": "2.25", "TagName": "Alti MW $ 2.25 |"}}
```

Con ese diccionario estoy queriendo trabajar. Busco copiar dichos valores dentro de mis variables:

```
Escriba el campo = "Alti MW $ 2 |"

#Packs para completar
TagName = "{}"
Floor_price = '{}'
Li_platform = '// * [@ id = "platform_listbox"] / li [{}]'
Excel_name = '{}'
Li_Publisher = '// * [@ id = "publisher_listbox"] / li [{}]'
Tag_Rate = '{}'
```

En escriba campo la idea es que uno coloque en este caso `"Alti MW $ 2 |"` o `"Alti MW $ 3 |"` y que en mis variables, dentro de cada {} se copien los datos del diccionario.

Para ser mas claro, necesito una funcion donde especifique "Alti MW $ 3 |" y me devuelva en las variables mas abajo todos sus valores. Tendria que quedar algo asi:

```
Escriba el campo = "Alti MW $ 2 |"
#Packs para completar
TagName = "Alti MW $ 2 |"
Floor_price = '2.8'
Li_platform = '// * [@ id = "platform_listbox"] / li [1]'
Excel_name = 'Alti MW $ 2.25.xlsx'
Li_Publisher = '// * [@ id = "publisher_listbox"] / li [2]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por empezar tu diccionario pareciera mal escrito o definido, la clave `"Alti MW $ 3 |"` está al mismo nivel que `"Inventario_datos"` entiendo que debiera estar al mismo nivel que `"Alti MW $ 2 |"`, revisa esto que digo, por que la solución esta condicionada a que el diccionario sea en realidad así:

```
Inventory_data = {"Inventario_datos": {"Alti MW $ 2 |": {"Floor_price": '2.5', "Li_platform": 1,
                                                    "Excel_name": "Alti MW $ 2.xlsx", "Li_Publisher": 2,
                                                    "Tag_Rate": "2", "TagName": "Alti MW $ 2 |"},
                                      "Alti MW $ 3 |": {"Floor_price": '2.75', "Li_platform": 1,
                                                    "Excel_name": "Alti MW $ 2.25.xlsx", "Li_Publisher": 2,
                                                    "Tag_Rate": "2.25", "TagName": "Alti MW $ 2.25 |"}
                                      }
}
```

Bien, lo que puedes hacer es crear una rutina que lea el diccionario y lo procese retornando cada valor requerido en tu ejemplo. Algo así:

```
def load_vars(key):
  d = (Inventory_data.get("Inventario_datos")).get(key)
  if d:
    return d.get("Floor_price", None), d.get("Li_platform", None), d.get("Excel_name", None), d.get("Li_Publisher", None) , d.get("Tag_Rate", None) , d.get("TagName", None)
  else:
    return None, None, None, None, None, None
```

Esta rutina además controla que exista el diccionario referenciado por el parámetro `key`, en caso contrario devolverá todos los valores como `None`, o también podrías emitir una excepción en ese caso y controlar la rutina con un bloque `try`. También si no existe alguno de los valores esperados en el diccionario podríamos devolver un valor "default" ya que justamente `get()` nos permite hacer esto.

Comment: Funciono a la perfecion! Muchas gracias